# why an global object (array) is not modified inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, reference

Since arrays and object are passed by reference with javascrit, why a global array modified inside a function is not modified after the function call ?

Here is a simple exemple of code :

```
      function test_update_KO(arr, arr_new)
      {
        arr = arr_new ;   
        console.log("inside function : OK the array is modified : " + JSON.stringify(arr)) ;
      }
      var arr_1 = [{ a:"val1"}] ;
      var arr_new = [{ a:"val new", b:"val b"}] ; 
      console.log("Before function function call :" + JSON.stringify(arr_1) ) ;
      test_update_KO(arr_1, arr_new);
      console.log("After function function call : the array is not modified !! why ?? : " + JSON.stringify(arr_1) ) ;
```

Comment: `arr` is a variable (parameter) local to `test_update_KO`. JavaScript does not pass by reference, so you're only updating that specific variable with the array.

Comment: it is actually a bit more complicated than that : Javascript Does pass by reference, but if you overwrite the reference, the original copy will not be affected.

Comment: it´s just not global what you doing when encapsulating into function and mixing variable names and parameter names

Comment: @BigBud52: That's not passing "by reference". A pass by reference system implies one where passing a variable is implicitly passing a reference *to the variable*, not to the value, and as such, updates to that reference are effectively updating the original variable. JS is always "pass by value", but some types are a "reference type", where you get a reference to the value itself.

Comment: ...so in your case, updating `arr` does not updte `arr_1`, which is what your example seems to suggest is your expectation. In a true "by reference" system, `arr_1` would be updated.

Comment: ...it's no more complicated. It's very simple. JS does not pass by reference as you suggested. Whatever you pass will be a copy, so your code copes what the original variable holds. The fact that it's copying a "reference type" isn't directly related to the question you posted.

Comment: So if you pass a copy, why is the copy modified if you changed one of it's element ?